Android objectbox - insert / put data increases native-part of memory, without freeing it
Referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78760216/...
I got the problem that put large data into the ob-database increases the native-part of memory in the Android Studio Profiler, which after that isn't freed up anymore.
So short description what I do:
I am parsing an xml-file from an url, creating EpgChannels (400) & EpgData (80.000) objects while parsing and save them in a separate list. After the parsing is finished I insert (put) the data into the database and I "fill" the toMany of each epg-channel with its related epgdata.
Following my current code for doing this:
 private fun addEpgDataToDatabase() {
        _epgProcessState.value = ExternEpgProcessState.EpgDataToDatabas

        if (isUpdating) {

            val existingDataQuery = epgDataBox.query().build()

            val existingDataIds = existingDataQuery.find()
                .map { it.idByAccountData }.toSet()
            existingDataQuery.close()

            val iterator = epgDataBatch.iterator()
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                val epg = iterator.next()
                if (existingDataIds.contains(epg.idByAccountData)) {
                    iterator.remove()
                }
            }
        }
        epgDataBox.store.runInTx {
            epgDataBatch.chunked(20000).forEach {
                epgDataBox.put(it)
            }
        }
        epgDataBox.closeThreadResources()

        _epgProcessState.value = ExternEpgProcessState.EpgDataToDatabasFinished

        addEpgDataToChannel()
    }

private fun addEpgDataToChannel() {
        _epgProcessState.value = ExternEpgProcessState.EpgChannelAndListToDatabase
        epgChannelBox.store.runInTx {
            epgChannelBatch.forEach { epgch ->
                epgch.epgDataList.addAll(epgDataBatch.filter { it.epChId == epgch.chEpgId })
            }
            epgChannelBox.put(epgChannelBatch)
        }
        epgChannelBox.closeThreadResources()
        _epgProcessState.value = ExternEpgProcessState.EpgChannelAndListToDatabaseFinished
        epgChannelBatch.clear()
        epgDataBatch.clear()
    }

As I got some (partially huge) lags while doing this - especially when using the app directly on my TV I investigated the memory Profiler. And that showed me an increase of the native-part when putting the data (especially the epgdata) into the database, that later isn't freed up anymore. I started to try some different batch-sizes, or if it's working better when putting all data at once, but the "problem" wasn't completely solved.  Particullary that it the native-part isn't freed up seemed strange to me.
It's freed up only after restart of the app.
So is there something I am missing? Or can I ignore this, like the part: Others of the Profiler (as objectbox is managing the memory automatically)?
Because I recognised also that if I add other xml-files the Native-part stays more or less the same, so it isn't increasing again. But what could cause the lags then? Putting to much data at once?
(I tried a smaller xml-file with only 15.000 epgdata and there I didn't noticed this)
And is epgDataBox.closeThreadResources() &  epgChannelBox.closeThreadResources() necessary in my code?
And another question: as there is no update/ignore conflict strategy (yet?), is there another way to put only new epgdata into the database or do I have to use something like the iterator in my code?

See the FAQ about "How much RAM is used?" on https://objectbox.io/faq/.
Edit: as for conflict strategies, see https://docs.objectbox.io/entity-annotations#unique-constraints

Hey Uwe.. I read this, but wasn't sure if that was exactly what I was talking about. Referring to the OnConflict Strategies, on github I read about plans to add Ignore and/or Update as Conflict Strategy, is this still up to date?

Maybe see the discussion on https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/733, might be more helpful. As for conflict strategies: yes, only FAIL and REPLACE are currently available.
